# cakePHP - before_filter not executed

Tags: cakephp

I have the following app_controller in app/controller.

the test function is never executed. If I put in the subclassed controller, its not executed there either. am I doing something wrong?

```
class AppController extends Controller {
 var $beforeFilter = array('test');

 function test() {
  var_dump('test');
  die();
 }

}
```

Comment: using debug() - a cakephp wrapper - is a lot nicer IMO than pr or var_dump.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

beforeFilter should be the actual function, not a variable (like helpers or components)..

```
   class AppController extends Controller {
        function beforeFilter(){
           pr('test');
        }
    }
```

Too, in your controllers you should call

```
parent::beforeFilter();
```

in *their* beforeFilter function. Since this is a static function, it need be an *actual* function :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. I was following documentation (though I can't find it again now) with the function callback above.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I guess the documentation I had was old. Works great now!